# Python: how to handle type hinting in subclasses?

Tags: python, types

I have a base class `Base` and a subclass `Sub`. I also have two other classes `BaseMember`, and `SubMember(BaseMember)`. The latter is a sub class of the former.

Now I simply want the base class to type hint that its functions returns `BaseMember`-objects while the sub class has functions which returns `SubMember` objects.

The functions themselves are exactly the same, only the type-hinting should differ. How does one accomplish this?

Here's some example code to get started.

```
Class Base:
    def __init__(self, member: BaseMember)
        self.member: BaseMember = member
    def get() -> BaseMember:
        return self.member

Class Sub(Base):
    def __init__(self, member: SubMember)
        self.member: SubMember = member
    def get() -> SubMember:
        return self.member
```

As you can see, there's a lot of repetitive code, despite the fact that the only thing that changes is the type hint.

Comment: (Just an opinion here) Your code shouldn't be driven by type-hinting. If the methods are the same in the subclass they should not be reimplemented. Having said that, you could just call `super().__init__(member)`, `return super().get()`, etc. if you really want to have correct type-hinting - that would make a bit more sense.